# Overwrite Check but want to stop rendering

Tags: rendering

First time rendering in Blender.

My 20 second video will be done in 10 hours, and I want to continue it tomorrow but I leave the "Overwrite* box check. Can I still stop and continue without losing the image that has been already rendered?

Comment: overwrite means it will overwrite already existing images with the same name. If you do a "normal" animation render, Blender automatically gives new name for each frame it renders - so i think you don't have to worry. Except you have already rendered the first 20 frames and did start the render again, then Blender will overwrite the first 20 again...yes.

Comment: and little hint for the future: "normally" if a render takes longer than 20 mins - you would make short little test renders whether everything works fine. You can do this by e.g. changing to eevee, scale down resolution to maybe 10% or whatever will be fast on your computer and then check wether it looks ok. If that's fine, change to your "full" render settings in maybe cycles, 100% resolution and samples 500 (or whatever)

Comment: Seeing how long it takes to render a single image would also give a hint as to how long the complete animation is likely to take. You could also render youre animation as a series of PNG images and then combine them all into your video using Blender afterwards which takes a matter of seconds.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks for the info! If i stop the rendering and uncheck the "Overwrite" then start it tomorrow. Will it not overwrite any existing images?

Comment: if you uncheck overwrite it will skip all frames which already were rendered as images (i hope you don't render as movie) and only render those frames which haven't been rendered before. Where as "already rendered" means: file with the name you specified in the the folder you specified exists - blender just appends the frame at the end.

Comment: As John commented, if a render takes so long, you should never ever render as any movie format but render as single images (.exr, .png or whatever you want). Reason for this is simple: if blender or your computer crashes, you start rendering from the beginning again. By unchecking overwrite you just have to render the "rest" which Blender does for you by unchecking. Of course you could also manually enter the frame start and frame end values in the render settings.

Comment: if you "in between" change the output path - this will **not** work - means: Blender renders everything again